# Can't start Tomcat - JDK installed but Tomcat says "NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE"

Tags: java, tomcat, startup, rhel, tomcat9

I'm running RHEL 7.9 and ran RPM to install JAVA 8 update 372, then un-tar'd my Tomcat packages so everything is "installed".  Then I set my .bashrc to:

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/"

So my $JAVA_HOME variable appears to work, but when I run my startup.sh script for tomcat I'm getting the error "NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE".  I'm confused because I installed the JDK and not the JRE and I'm not finding any good threads about this.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Ran a few different variations of .bashrc to no avail.  Should I not point to the bin folder of my tomcat install?

Comment: What if you try `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64"`?

Comment: Looks like same deal:
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Comment: I ran "java -version" and it is showing "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_381-b09)"... Why is JRE installed when I installed the JDK???

Answer (score 0):

Still don't understand but... Originally I installed  JAVA JDK 8 update 381 (jdk-8u381-linux-x64.rpm).  I downloaded a new version of JAVA JDK 19 (jdk-19.0.2_linux-x64_bin.rpm), ran the RPM installation, set the environment variable to "export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-19-oracle-x64/"" and tomcat started without issues.

Comment: Please use the comment feature to add information like that or edit your question if the new information is relevant for the question itself too.